# Finding all values in a Dictionary<string, object> where value contains substring

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, object> ItemSource;
```

I want to select items that value contains a string.

Here's the code that I'm using

```
var ItemSource=_db.Users.ToDictionary(m=>m.FullName,M=>M.UserName as object);
var source=ItemSource.Where(a => a.Value.ToString().Contains(pattern))
```

But this return all items.

Items in ItemsSorce is

```
{[11,رحیمی]}
{12,سالاری}
{13,محمدی}
```

Comment: Did you forgot to assign to ItemSource? ItemSource = ItemSource.Where(a => a.Value.ToString().Contains(pattern))

Comment: No, I write only linq code in question.

Comment: Can you show some sample data? What you are storing in `object` of dictionary?

Comment: Hello I've tried reproducing your problem at this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/jOvQnw but the result is normal, can you help to modify this to reproduce your problem?

Comment: I see no problems in your code. What's the problem? If every value in your test data contains the substring, it's normal to return all items.

Comment: PLZ see my edit. I use "ر" in Contain , but don't return correct value.

Comment: Oh I can see that both data contains the "ر" character, so what's your expected result?　https://dotnetfiddle.net/jOvQnw

Comment: Sorry, 
 I had forgotten to write One of the items.I edited.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/rxrDqA　The result is OK...

Comment: @User2012384 : It is ok Thanks a lot  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:-

```
ItemSource.Where(a=> a.Key.Contains(pattern)).Select(a=> a.Value);
```

**EDIT:**

```
var source = ItemSource.Where(a=> a.Value == pattern).Select(a=> a.Key);
```

Comment: Thanks, But value in `Object` and don't can use `Contains` for it.

Comment: @ar.gorgin:- Updated my answer. Please check now!

Comment: Thanks, but i want to search with Value.

Comment: @ar.gorgin:- Updated that!

Comment: I want to serach a value like pattern in ItemSource. but this code select items that equal.

Comment: @ar.gorgin:- I have added the second option as well!

Comment: Value is `Object` and  don't have `Contains` function.